# Программное определение наименования модели телефона

Tags: java, android, java.lang.system

В связи с предыдущим вопросом возник этот — как из приложения определить имя модели телефона, чтобы в соответствии с ним под конкретную модель выполнять конкретные действия.

Единственное, что сам накопал - это `System.getProperties();`
Возвращает перечень свойств системы. Там имеется св-во `http.agent`, где в составе длинной строки описания присутствует имя модели телефона.

Например для `Samsung Galaxy Ace` она выглядит так:

```
Dalvik/1.4.0(Linux; U;  Android 2.3.5; GT-S5830 Build/GINGERBREAD)
```

Где собственно `GT-S5830` — модель телефона.

Для `HTC Desire` по аналогии строчка и прям так и написано в ней `HTC Desire` :)

К сожалению, мог проверить только на 2-х аппаратах, что это свойство есть, и имя там присутствует. Как будет на других — не знаю.
Поэтому и обращаюсь с вопросом: по этому свойству однозначно можно выцепить модель телефона или же есть другой, более надежный метод?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
public String getDeviceName() {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
        return capitalize(model);
    } else {
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}

private String capitalize(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    char first = s.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Парочка примеров того, что будет:

```
Samsung GT-S5830L
Motorola MB860
Sony Ericsson LT18i
LGE LG-P500
HTC Desire V
HTC Wildfire S A510e
```

Comment: ага. спасибо. только что такое же выдал гугл :)
уже пробую.